# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^\alpha}=1,\alpha>0$, find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ using definite integral.

Tags: calculus

So.. this looks pretty much like a reimann sum, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}$$ something but it doesn't seem to be able to be written as a reimann sum.....is the final answer 1? I took a guess by grouping $n^\alpha$ to the $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ part, which would result in $n$ 1s and which would cancel out with the n at the denominator ....okay that's not rigorous I know.  Any leads? Thanks!

Comment: Trying with a few values of $\alpha$ and taking $a_n=n^\alpha$, the answer seems to be $\dfrac 1{\alpha+1}$. Can you find a way to relate the latter limit to $\int\limits_0^1 x^\alpha~\mathrm dx$?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{k}{n})^\alpha\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{k^\alpha}$ but the second sum is mildly annoying.

Comment: I posted an answer; see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha$ and $c_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. Then (the "Riemann sum" argument) $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{n^{1+\alpha}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^\alpha=\int_0^1 x^\alpha\,dx=\frac{1}{1+\alpha},$$ and we're given $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c_n-c_{n-1}}{b_n-b_{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^\alpha}=1$.

Hence $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c_n}{b_n}=1$ by [Stolz–Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c_n}{n^{1+\alpha}}=\frac{1}{1+\alpha}$ by the above.

Answer (score 0):

The demand is weird because the definite integral does not play the central role in this limit.
This problem may seem opaque somehow to you but let us rephrase it another way by giving you a lemma, then I guess everything will be clear to you.

**Lemma**: Let $(u_n; n \ge 0)$ and $( w_n; n \ge 0)$ be two real sequences such that:

- $w_n>0$
- $\lim_{n \rightarrow + \infty} \left( w_1+w_2+...+w_n \right) =+ \infty$
- $u_n$ has a limit, that is $ \exists u $ such that $ \lim u_n=u$
  then,
  $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{w_1u_1+w_2u_2+...+w_nu_n}{w_1+w_2+...+w_n}=u $$

Then you apply the above lemma for our problem with $u_n=\dfrac{a_n}{n^{\alpha}}$, $w_n=n^{\alpha}$.

Comment: The demand is indeed written in the question and the question is from the chapter for definite integrals-- but thanks for your help! Can the lemma be proved?

Comment: Not much of problem. For simplicity,  assume $u=0$, due to the convergence, for every $\epsilon>0$ we can find $N$ such that $$|u_n|<\epsilon \space \forall n>N$$ that makes : $$\vert LHS \vert \le \vert \dfrac{| w_1u_1+...+w_Nu_N|}{w_1+...+w_n} +|\epsilon|$$ which implies $$ \limsup LHS  \le \epsilon$$ .QED.

Comment: This is not correct: your denominator $\sum w_k$ is $\sum k^\alpha$ which doesn't equal $n^{1+\alpha}$. Your lemma answers that $\dfrac{a_k}{\sum k^\alpha}\to 1$ as $k\to\infty$ which is **not** the limit in OP's question.

Comment: Man, that term does not mean much. We always have a limit for $$\dfrac{ \sum_{k=1}^n k^{\alpha}}{n^{1+\alpha}}$$ Why are you making a fuss for so little.

Comment: Your answer doesn't correspond to OP's limit: it's a different limit that is 1; OP's limit equals $1/(1+\alpha)$

Comment: Also, that is the easiest part.

Comment: I don't think you understand my comment: your lemma using the $u_n,w_n$ you suggest shows that $\dfrac{\sum_1^n a_k}{\sum_1^n k^\alpha}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$ which is **not** the same as the limit asked in OP's question. I had a typo in my previous comment (which I cannot edit now, alas!) but my point still stands.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas  Well, I guess you don't understand my reply. I said that the point you made in your previous comment is of little significance. Put it this way, if you are to find the limit of a sequence , say $$ \lim \dfrac{A_n}{B_n}$$. But you can find another sequence $C_n$ so that $\frac{C_n}{B_n}$ exists and  is extremely easy to manipulate.  So what's the hard part is? That is to find make a sense for the limit $A_n/C_n$. And that's what I did. Man.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac 1{n^{1+\alpha}}\sum_1^n a_k=\frac 1n\sum_1^n\frac{a_k}{n^\alpha}$$

Since $a_k/k^\alpha\to 1$ as $k\to\infty$, we have $a_k\to k^\alpha$ as $k\to\infty$, so,

$$\frac 1n\sum_1^n\frac{a_k}{n^\alpha}\to\frac 1n\sum_1^n\frac{k^\alpha}{n^\alpha}\to\frac 1n\sum_1^n(k/n)^\alpha\overset{?}{\to}\int_0^1 x^\alpha~\mathrm dx=\frac 1{1+\alpha}$$

as $n\to\infty$

---

The above might seem suspect because I'm ignoring initial values of $a_k$ and just substituting the asymptotic form for $a_k$ as if assuming the limit to be with $k\to\infty$ as well, so here's a bit of formalism to justify:

$a_k/k^\alpha\to 1$ or that $a_k\to k^\alpha$ as $k\to\infty$ is equivalent to saying that given any $\epsilon\gt 0$, we have $a_k\in (k^\alpha-\epsilon,k^\alpha+\epsilon)$ for sufficiently large $k$, say for all $k\geq k_0$ for some $k_0\in\Bbb N$

So, we can write,

$$\sum_1^n\frac{a_k}{n^{1+\alpha}}=\sum_1^{k_0}\frac{a_k}{n^{1+\alpha}}+\sum_{k_0}^n\frac{a_k}{n^{1+\alpha}}$$

so taking $\epsilon$ to be sufficiently small, $a_k\approx k^\alpha$ for all $k\geq k_0$ and for the sum from $1$ to $k_0$, the $a_k$ are finite but the denominator $n^{1+\alpha}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ since $1+\alpha\gt 1$, so that summand vanishes when $n\to\infty$ and we're left with the latter sum from $k_0$ to $n$ where you can replace $a_k$ by $k^\alpha$ and note that removing finitely many elements from a Riemann sum doesn't change the value, so we conclude, ie, as $n\to\infty$,

$$\sum_1^n\frac{a_k}{n^{1+\alpha}}\to\sum_{k_0}^n\frac{a_k}{n^{1+\alpha}}\to\frac 1n\sum_{k_0}^n\frac{k^\alpha}{n^\alpha}\to\frac 1n\sum_1^n\frac{k^\alpha}{n^\alpha}\dots$$